# Show that the common chord of the circles with diameters $CM$ and $BN$ pass through $H$ given that $M\in AB, N\in AC$

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

> If $\Delta ABC$ is non-right angled with orthocenter $H$, show that
>   the common chord of the circles with diameters $CM$ and $BN$ pass
>   through $H$ given that $M\in AB, N\in AC$

I have a synthetic/pure geometric Solution using power of points and radical axis but I don't really understand what's wrong in my coordinate bash.

Let $BE\perp AC, AD\perp BC, CF\perp AB$. Denote $B(-b,0), D(0,0), C(c,0), A(0,a)$.

The calculations have been omitted. The $x-$ coordinate of $M,N$ be $m,n$ respectively. And we find the $y-$ coordinate from the equation of $AB, AC$ respectively.

Therefore, $M\equiv (m, a+\frac{am}{b}), N\equiv (n,a-\frac{an}{c})$

Point $E$ can be found out from the fact that $BE\perp AC$ and that $E$ satisfies the equation of $AC$. It turns out to be $E\equiv \left( \frac{a^2c-bc^2}{a^2+c^2}, \frac{ac(b+c)}{a^2+c^2}\right)$.

Now $H$ is of the from $(0,h)$ and by some computation, I got $$H\equiv \left(0, \frac{ac(b+c)}{a^2+c^2}\left[ 1- \frac{a^c-bc^2}{ac(b+c)+b(a^2+c^2)}\right] \right)$$

If we show that $H\in \text{radical axis}$ of the two circles, we are done.

The equation of circle with diameter $BN$ is $(x-n)(x+b)+(y-a+\frac{an}{c})y=0$ and similarly the equation of circle with diameter $CM$ is $(x-c)(x-m)+(y-a-\frac{am}{b})y=0$.

The radical axis can be obtained by subtracting the two equations upon which we get $$x(b+c+m-n)+y\left(\frac{am}{b}+\frac{an}{c}\right)-(bn+cm)=0$$.

But $H$ doesn't satisfy this equation.

May I know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found no errors in the coordinates of $M,N,E$.

I found an error in the coordinates of $H$.

The equation of the line $BE$ is given by
$$y-0=\frac{\frac{ac(b+c)}{a^2+c^2}-0}{\frac{a^2c-bc^2}{a^2+c^2}-(-b)}(x-(-b)),$$
i.e.
$$y=\frac{c}{a}(x+b)$$
from which
$$H\left(0,\frac{bc}{a}\right)$$
follows.